# Show a logged in user their own information from a database model

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-forms

I am relatively new to Django, and web development in general. Basically, I'm trying to build a website with two types of users: customers, and suppliers. Both the customers and suppliers have user accounts (containing a username, email, and password) created using Django's built-in 'from django.contrib.auth import login -forms.Form' and stored in the table 'auth_user' in my mySQL database.

But, the suppliers can also create a more detailed profile (name, bio, images etc) which is created using a 'forms.ModelForm' called 'SupplierSignupForm' and stored in a separate table to 'auth_user', called 'home_suppliersignup'.

What I want to happen is, when a supplier is logged in, they can click on their 'my profile' link in the header and be taken to their profile located in the 'home_suppliersignup' table in my database. Currently, I know how to call a logged in users ID from the table 'auth_user' using their session info, and then use that to link to their respective 'auth_user' profile:

views.py

```
    user = request.user
```

template

```
    <a href="{% url 'supplier_profile' id=user.id %}">My profile</a>
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^supplier-profile/(?P<id>[0-9]+)', supplier_profile, name="supplier_profile")
```

But I don't know how to use this to pull up their information from another database table (i.e. home_suppliersignup).

Any help would be much appreciated!

My current code:

models.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class SupplierSignUp(models.Model):

        LOCATION_CHOICES=(
            ("Central London", "Central London"),
            ("North London", "North London"),
            ("East London", "East London"),
            ("South London", "South London"),
            ("West London", "West London"),
        )

        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        area = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, null=True)
        booking_link = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("supplier_profile", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import SupplierSignUp
    from django.contrib.auth import (
        authenticate,
        get_user_model,
        login,
        logout,
        )
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

    User = get_user_model()

    class SupplierSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = SupplierSignUp
            fields = ['name', 'bio', 'area', 'booking_link']

    class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField()
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
            username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

            if username and password:
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if not user:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")

                if not user.check_password(password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")

                if not user.is_active:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active")

            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField()
        email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address")
        email2 = forms.EmailField(label="Confirm Email", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'false'}))
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'username',
                'email',
                'email2',
                'password',
            ]

        def clean_email2(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
            if email != email2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must match")

            email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if email_qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")

            return email
```

Comment: Show the models.py where I assume you have a relationship between the user model and the supplierssignup model (because you probably need that relationship for this to work).

Comment: Do you mean pull from another database's table? multi databases ?

Comment: @wobbily_col Thanks for your quick response. I've updated my post to include my current 'models.py' and 'forms.py' code. What do you mean by a relationship? How would I set this up?

Comment: @aircraft yes exactly. I want to pull the logged in users data from a database table (I assume the easiest way is to use his 'id' from the session e.g. user = request.user ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are *not* using a class based generic views, try this:

```
user=request.user 
SupplierSignUp.objects.get(user=user)
```

You are taking the logged in user from the request, do there is no need to specify the user id in your urls.py / template (unless you want users to be able to see each others profile).